# Is there an equivalent of FSC_COLOR in GDL?

Tags: idl

I am trying to run my IDL programs at home in GDL. Among other problems I run into this one:

```
GDL> bk=fsc_color('Black')
% Ambiguous: Variable is undefined: FSC_COLOR or: Function not found: FSC_COLOR
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

Is there a way to get colours by name in GDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you just haven't put `fsc_color.pro` in your `!path` (or the GDL equivalent). `FSC_COLOR` is not provided by the IDL distribution; you have to install it and tell IDL where it is located.